# How to Add Grid to ControlTemplate in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want add grid to ControlTemplate using C# in UWP application

For example I have XAML code like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
<Grid Name="RootGrid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Grid>
```

And i want to do it from C# like, ControlTemplate not have Child or Children

```
Grid grid1 = new Grid();
ControlTemplate cTempl = new ControlTemplate();
cTempl.child.add(grid1);
```

Comment: A template is a template and you don't create an instance of a control at runtime and add it to a template. If you want to create a template programmatically, you should use the XamlReader.Load method as suggested by Sunteen Wu. But defining a template in XAML and then try to modify it programmatically at runtime makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to change the `ControlTemplate` code behind, but this is not recommended. According to the remarks of the [`ControlTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate) class:

> Control templates provide the visuals and parts that make up an instance of a control as it appears in an app's UI. At run time, the template has already been applied, and so all the parts that were created out of the template are now truly parts of the control.

The template has already be applied at run time and there are really only two properties you use when defining a `ControlTemplate`: the `TargetType`, and the implicit XAML. If you do want to set it code behind, you may try to use [`XamlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader) for parsing XAML, for example:

```
const string xaml = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Rectangle Stroke=\"Red\" StrokeThickness=\"3\" /></ControlTemplate>";
ControlTemplate сt=(ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

Again, this is not recommended. Think about why you need this feature. You could directly change it in XAML, or create a custom control to set your own `ControlTemplate` with `OnApplyTemplate` method.

Comment: Sunteen, Thank you. As per my requirement i should not touch the XAML. And i am doing this by using template (Which you provided as not recommended example). But i am looking for solution from code-behind.

Comment: @Mahesh As I mentioned above,  there are really only two properties you use when defining a `ControlTemplate`, you cannot set it code behind. Think about your requirements and try other ways. And check the last paragraph I mentioned.

Comment: Did you mean .Parse(xaml)?