# How can I translate this .XAML code into C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, code-translation

I need some help translating the following .XAML code below to its corresponding C# code:

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="MenuImageContextMenu" Background="White" Width="175" Height="100">
    <ContextMenu.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="ContextMenuGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <Grid x:Name="BeverageGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="50">
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                      <Image x:Name="BeverageImage" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Source="/DinerPOS;component/Resources/Images/Restaurant/Beverages/Beverage.png" Stretch="Fill" />

                      <TextBlock x:Name="BeverageLabel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Text="Beverages" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                 </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.Template>
</ContextMenu>
```

What I have tried so far

```
ContextMenu ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
ControlTemplate ControlTemplate = new ControlTemplate();

// ControlTemplate.VisualTree = Grid ????

ContextMenu.Name = MenuImageContextMenu;
ContextMenu.Template = ControlTemplate;
```

But I don't know how to add the main Grid `ContextMenuGrid` to the `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Grid to ControlTemplate in UWP C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457394/how-to-add-grid-to-controltemplate-in-uwp-c-sharp)

Comment: @MarkBaijens I need the ContextMenu to show up at a certain position programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `XamlReader.Parse` to create a `ContextMenu` element from a XAML string:

```
const string Xaml = "<ContextMenu xmlns =\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" " +
          "Background=\"White\" Width=\"175\" Height=\"100\"> " +
          "    <ContextMenu.Template> " +
          "        <ControlTemplate> " +
          "            <Grid x:Name=\"ContextMenuGrid\" Background=\"{TemplateBinding Background}\"> " +
          "                  <Grid x:Name=\"BeverageGrid\" Background=\"{TemplateBinding Background}\" Height=\"50\"> " +
          "                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> " +
          "                          <ColumnDefinition Width=\"0.5*\" /> " +
          "                          <ColumnDefinition Width=\"3.5*\" /> " +
          "                          <ColumnDefinition Width=\"6*\" /> " +
          "                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> " +
          "                      <Image Grid.Column=\"1\" Grid.RowSpan=\"3\" Source=\"/DinerPOS;component/Resources/Images/Restaurant/Beverages/Beverage.png\" Stretch=\"Fill\" /> " +
          "                      <TextBlock Grid.Column=\"2\" Grid.RowSpan=\"3\" Text=\"Beverages\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\" TextAlignment=\"Center\" VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" /> " +
          "                 </Grid> " +
          "            </Grid> " +
          "        </ControlTemplate> " +
          "    </ContextMenu.Template> " +
          "</ContextMenu>";
ContextMenu ct = XamlReader.Parse(Xaml) as ContextMenu;
```

Comment: Is this recommended? It seems like hack (it's appreciated, though).

Comment: @soulblazer: Yes. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=netframework-4.7.2): "The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class."